# How to use set! on "anything" in scheme?

Tags: scheme, racket

I am using DrRacket.

This works:

```
(define foo 1)
(set! foo 2)
foo ;;returns 2
```

But here I want *foo* to return 2:

```
(define foo 1)
(define (setmachine variable newvalue)
    (set! variable newvalue))
(setmachine foo 2)
foo ;; returns 1
```

How can I make the *setmachine* work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine I do this:

```
(define bla 10)
(define test bla)
(set! test 20)
```

What does the third line do? Does it change `bla`? that is how you assuming your `setmachine` should work.

```
(set! variable newvalue)
```

This changes the variable named `variable`, not the variable named `foo`.
Your set-machine works, but not as you intended!

```
(define (setmachine variable newvalue)
  (display variable)       ; displays the value to variable
  (set! variable newvalue) ; changes the binding to the value of newvalue
  (display variable))      ; displays the value of variable (same as newvalue)

(define foo 1)
(setmachine foo 2) ; displays 1, then 2
```

See it did mutate `variable`, but not `foo`. In fact if you passed it 1 instead of `foo` it still works since it passes arguments by value. You didn't instruct it to change `foo`. Here is how to do that:

```
(define-syntax syntaxset
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ name expression)
     (set! name expression))))

(define foo 1)
(syntaxset foo 2)
foo ; ==> 2
```

This is no longer a procedure. In fact what happens is that before the program runs racket will have modified the code from `(syntaxset foo 2)` to `(set! foo 2)`

Now if you try to do `(syntaxset 1 2)` to redefine all accurences of `1` in your code to evaluate to `2` it doesn't work since it becomes `(set! 1 2)` and `set!` expects the first argument to be a symbolic expression.

Comment: This is great thanks! Very well described! I have only seen define-syntax once before, and will definitely check out the documentation now.